# Last Query Executed would not show in cake2php using getlog()

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mysql-workbench, cakephp-2.0

ive tried to get the last query of the sql statement using the getlog function from cake2. What i would normally get would be the sql query but instead what i got is this :

```
$sample: array(3)
  0: array(5)
      query: "Commit"
      params : array(0)
      affected : false 
      numRows : false
      took : false
```

i tried to match the data entered in the database by unsetting some array data but it still gets that output as mentioned above. Does anyone know how to get the sql query from the save function? Thanks in advance

Here is the code :

```
 public function mod_edit_confirm() {
    $data = $this->Session->read('data_product_edit');

    $title = 'Product Edit Confirmation';
    $button = 'Update';
    $link = '/products/edit/'.$data['MstProduct']['id'];
    $product_type = $this->MstProductType->findById($data['MstProduct']['product_type_id']);
    if(isset($data['MstProduct']['sales_price']) && $data['MstProduct']['sales_price'] != ''){
        $data['MstProduct']['sales_price'] = number_format($data['MstProduct']['sales_price']);
    }
    if(isset($data['MstProduct']['adjustment_of_amount_of_tax_exclusive']) && $data['MstProduct']['adjustment_of_amount_of_tax_exclusive'] != ''){
        $data['MstProduct']['adjustment_of_amount_of_tax_exclusive'] = number_format($data['MstProduct']['adjustment_of_amount_of_tax_exclusive']);
    }
    if(isset($data['MstProduct']['price_of_option_or_goods']) && $data['MstProduct']['price_of_option_or_goods'] != ''){
        $data['MstProduct']['price_of_option_or_goods'] = number_format($data['MstProduct']['price_of_option_or_goods']);
    }
    if(isset($data['MstProduct']['display_price_without_tax']) && $data['MstProduct']['display_price_without_tax'] != ''){
        $data['MstProduct']['display_price_without_tax'] = number_format($data['MstProduct']['display_price_without_tax']);
    }
    if(isset($data['MstProduct']['amount_of_charge_points']) && $data['MstProduct']['amount_of_charge_points'] != ''){
        $data['MstProduct']['amount_of_charge_points'] = number_format($data['MstProduct']['amount_of_charge_points']);
    }
    if(isset($data['MstProduct']['amount_of_bonus_points']) && $data['MstProduct']['amount_of_bonus_points'] != ''){
        $data['MstProduct']['amount_of_bonus_points'] = number_format($data['MstProduct']['amount_of_bonus_points']);
    }

    $category = $this->Category->findById($data['MstProduct']['category_id']);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //click register product
        if (isset($this->request->data['Save'])) {
            $data = $this->Session->read('data_product_edit');
            if ($data['MstProduct']['color_1'] != '')
                $data['MstProduct']['color_1'] = trim($data['MstProduct']['color_1'],"#");

            if ($data['MstProduct']['color_2'] != '')
                $data['MstProduct']['color_2'] = trim($data['MstProduct']['color_2'],"#");

            unset($data['MstProduct']['end_radio']);
            unset($data['MstProduct']['start_radio']);
            unset($data['MstProduct']['category1']);
            unset($data['MstProduct']['category2']);
            unset($data['MstProduct']['category3']);
            unset($data['MstProduct']['category4']);
            unset($data['MstProduct']['category5']);
            unset($data['Confirm']);
            $this->MstProduct->id = $data['MstProduct']['id'];
            if ($this->MstProduct->save($data)) {
                // here is where i get my datalogs
                $sample=$this->MstProduct->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
                $this->Session->delete('data_product_edit');
                if ($data['MstProduct']['product_type_id'] == 1) {
                    $this->MstProduct->saveField('amount_of_charge_points', '');
                } else if ($data['MstProduct']['product_type_id'] == 2) {
                    $this->MstProduct->saveField('treatment_minutes', '');
                } else {
                    $this->MstProduct->saveField('treatment_minutes', '');
                    $this->MstProduct->saveField('amount_of_charge_points', '');
                }
                $this->Flash->success(__d('admin', 'Successfully Updated.'));
                return $this->redirect('/products/edit/complete');
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__d('admin', 'Updated Faild.'));
                return $this->redirect('/products/edit/'.$data['MstProduct']['id']);
            }
        } else if (isset($this->request->data['Cancel'])) {
            $this->Session->delete('data_product_edit');
            return $this->redirect('/products');
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('data', 'product_type', 'title', 'link', 'category', 'button'));
    $this->render("mod_add_confirm");
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem.

The problem was that i dont have beforesave() and aftersave() in the model. Make sure those are both created and returns true.